# Why my answer get Time Limit Exceeded error?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

For LeetCode question *170. Two Sum III - Data structure design* I got Time Limit Exceeded error. As my own check, my algorithm complexity is O(nlogn) which *sort* in *add* function will cost O(nlogn) and *find* function will cost O(n). This complexity is same as the solution given. Can anyone help me find out why this happen?
This is my code:

```
// #include <alogorithm>
// #include <vector>
// #include "TwoSum.h"
// v type is vector<int> and which is the only variable in class

TwoSum::TwoSum() {}

void TwoSum::add(int number) {
    v.push_back(number);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}

bool TwoSum::find(int value) {
    if (v.empty() || v.size() == 1)
        return false;

    int front = 0;
    int back = v.size() - 1;
    while (front != back) {
        if (v[front] + v[back] < value)
            front++;
        else if (v[front] + v[back] > value)
            back--;
        else
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The complexity of your `TwoSum::add` is not O(N log N). It is O(1 log(1) + 2 log(2) + ... + N log N), that is O(N^2 log N).

Comment: Use a map to find the target value.

Comment: There are much more efficient ways to insert a value into a sorted vector than adding it at the end then sorting

Comment: Especially if the sorting algorithm is not optimized for that specific case (everything sorted, except last element).

Comment: Oh you are right. I was too focused on the sort() itself. Thank you!

Comment: Sorting algorithms can be `O(n*log N)` in general, testing for last element wrong can be `O(n)`, sorted inserting is `O(log n)`. So it would be definitely slower.